# How to create notification bar in android?

Tags: android, android-notification-bar

I am new in Android Programming. I have created two classes **IncomingSms.java** & **BroadcastNewSms.java**.
**Code: IncomingSms.java**

```
package com.example.broadcastreceivernewsms;

public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Get the object of SmsManager
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
        //String[] projection = new String[] { "_id", "address", "person", "body", "date", "type" };
        //Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, "address='51555'", null, "date desc");

        // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + senderNum + "; message: " + message);


                    // Show Alert
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
                            "senderNum: " + senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                    toast.show();

                } // end for loop
            } // bundle is null

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" + e);

        }
    }


}
```

**Code:BroadcastNewSms.java**

```
public class BroadcastNewSms extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_broadcast_new_sms);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_broadcast_new_sms, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

It works fine.When I run the app & whenever a new sms comes into my device it prints the sender number & messagebody into the Toast.
  Now my question is that,how can I create a message in Notification bar that "A New message received"(Like whenever we receive a sms in Whatsapp it prints give a notification in notificatiobar,if the app is not running directly) whenever a new message received into my device.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the code below, there is example how to create notification:

To display notification you need context object

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        final Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.your_ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle("tite"/*your notification title*/)
                .setContentText("Some example context string"/*notifcation message*/)
                .build();
        notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(1000/*some int*/, notification);
}
```

Comment: In which class in which method I will write this particular code you have mentioned above, to get the notification whenever I receive the message into my device?

Comment: In the place where you want to display notification additionally you need set notification manager variable by ((NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)

Comment: You can run this code in the onReceive(Context context, Intent intet) method

Comment: Okay waiting for your update in your code so that I can use in my above mentioned code.Please Help me out!

Comment: Please give me the code according to my code.I am not getting it.

Comment: If you copy my code to onReceive and inserted your data such as title and content text you will get notification.

Comment: I created gist with your code https://gist.github.com/KKonradMC/d9c18dbe18718bff1ff0

Comment: But I am not sure that it is good idea to create notification in loop, Toast too.

Comment: Its working Thank You! But I want when I click over the notification it opens up my application.How could I do this?

Comment: You have to use PendingIntent and add it to notification by setContentIntent(yourIntent) method